# RecyclerView Viewholder reusing

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am creating a `RecyclerView` which will expand itself when the user touches it and closes itself when the user touches it again. Below is my code:

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.RecViewHolder> {
    ArrayList<String> values;
    ArrayList<Integer> expandedPosition;
    public static class RecViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ...
        private boolean resultsOpened = false;
        ...
        RelativeLayout favHeaderLayout;
        RelativeLayout favResultsLayout;

        public RecViewHolder (View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            favHeaderLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (!resultsOpened) {
                        expandLayout();
                    } else {
                        favResultsLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        resultsOpened = false;
                    }
                }
            });

        }

        public void expandLayout() {
            favResultsLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            resultsOpened = true;
            //I populate my expanded layout here
        }
    }

    public RecyclerViewAdapter (Context context, ArrayList<String> values) {
        this.context = context;
        this.values= values;
    }

    @Override
    public RecViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_file, parent, false);
        RecViewHolder recViewHolder= new RecViewHolder(v);
        return recViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecViewHolder recViewHolder , int position) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return values.size();
    }

}
```

When I touch the first view, it should expand itself. However, when the adapter has more data and I touch the first view, the view expands and another view at the bottom of the `RecyclerView` (e.g. the 8th view) expands too. How do I ensure that only the view that have been touched expand the the other stays close?

**EDIT**

I've tried storing the expanded Views position in an arraylist and in `onBindViewHolder`, check which views are expanded and expand them only:

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.RecViewHolder> {
    ArrayList<String> values;
    ArrayList<Integer> expandedPosition;
    public static class RecViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ...
        private boolean resultsOpened = false;
        ...
        RelativeLayout favHeaderLayout;
        RelativeLayout favResultsLayout;

        public RecViewHolder (View itemView) {
            super(itemView);


        }

    }

    public RecyclerViewAdapter (Context context, ArrayList<String> values) {
        this.context = context;
        this.values= values;
    }

    @Override
    public RecViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_file, parent, false);
        RecViewHolder recViewHolder= new RecViewHolder(v);
        return recViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecViewHolder recViewHolder , int position) {
        recViewHolder.favResultsLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        for(int i= 0; i < expandedPosition.size(); i ++){
            recViewHolder.favResultsLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        recViewHolder.favHeaderLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                     if (!expandedPosition.contains(position)) {
                        expandLayout(recViewHolder);
                        expandedPosition.add(position);
                    } else {
                        recViewHolder.favResultsLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        for(int i = 0; i < expandedPosition.size(); i ++){
                            if (expandedPosition.get(i) == position){
                                    expandedPosition.remove(i);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
    }
    public void expandLayout() {
            favResultsLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //I populate my expanded layout here
        }
    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return values.size();
    }

}
```

Still no luck :(

Comment: How do you define your favResultsLayout?

Comment: obviously you have to store expanded items(set of expanded item's positions should be ok) in Adapter or in item itself(not posible now with String you have to use custom class like `Item { public String String1; public boolean Expanded }` ) and use this information to setup view holder in `onBindViewHolder` .... view holders count used by adapter != items count of underlaying data ... remeber about this

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Below are the codes for favResultsLayout
favResultsLayout = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.fav_results_layout);

The xml: 
<RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/fav_results_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone">
                <!--GridView here-->
            </RelativeLayout>

Comment: @SpencerRoi it doesn't matter ... try to implement my comment

Comment: Hi, I did something similar, where I stored the position of the views that were expanded in an arraylist and in onBindViewHolder i set the expanded layout to GONE by default and only set the visibility to VISIBLE only for views that are in the arraylist. It didn't work though.. I also tried adding the views into an ArrayList and comparing it.. No luck too. Was that a right approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the class name says it is all about recycling ...

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.RecViewHolder> {
    ArrayList<String> values;
    SparseBooleanArray expanded = new SparseBooleanArray();
    public static class RecViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        //EDIT!!!!!
        public RecViewHolder (View itemView, final RecyclerViewAdapter adapter) {
        //rest of the code ...
        favHeaderLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) { 
                final int currentPosition = getAdapterPosition();
                //is a view at current position expanded?
                if(adapter.expanded.get(currentPosition ))
                    //if so it shouldn't be
                    adapter.expanded.delete(getAdapterPosition(currentPosition));
                else
                    //if not, expand
                    adapter.expanded.put(currentPosition, true);
                //wheeee inform the adapter to rebind
                adapter.notifyItemChanged(currentPosition);
                //setupExpanded(expanded.get(currentPosition)); 
            }
        });
        }
        protected void setupExpanded(boolean state) {
        //ONLY hide show layouts based on state
        }
    }
    @Override
    public RecViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_file, parent, false);
        RecViewHolder recViewHolder= new RecViewHolder(v, this);
        return recViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecViewHolder recViewHolder , int position)    {
        //this line should be self explanatory
        recViewHolder.setupExpanded(expanded.get(position));
    }

    //rest of the code
}
```

Comment: Hi Selvin,

Thanks for the great explanation! It's working now! :D

Comment: I have another question though... When I expand the layout, during the first expansion the scroll bar stays at the favHeaderLayout position. However, subsequent expansion causes the scrollbar to jump to the middle of favResultsLayout. Is there anyway to force the scrollbar to always stay at the favHeaderLayout position when pressed?

Comment: Yes, notify the adapter that item has changed

Comment: @SpencerRoi try it now ... in old solution RecyclerView did not know that layout size had changed in onClick

Comment: @SpencerRoi hehe setting currentPosition is redundant as we have getAdapterPosition() inside ViewHolder ... fixed