# Removing an item from RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a problem when I am removing an item from my list in my RecycerView. I want to do the following functionality. When I press a checkbox in my RecycerView list the item is to be removed from the list. Basically this works when I press some of the top/bottom checkboxes, but when I press some in-between I have other checkboxes are marked as Checked without even touching them. I don't know where this problem comes from.

[image]

This is my code in my adapter:

```
public class ShoppingListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ShoppingListAdapter.ShoppingListViewHolder> {
private ArrayList<Item> mItems;
private Context mContext;

public ShoppingListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Item> items) {
    mItems = items;
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
public ShoppingListViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int position) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.shopping_list_item,viewGroup,false);
    ShoppingListViewHolder viewHolder = new ShoppingListViewHolder(view);

    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ShoppingListViewHolder shoppingListViewHolder, int position) {
    shoppingListViewHolder.bindShoppingList(mItems.get(position));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mItems.size();
}

public class ShoppingListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener{
    public TextView mShoppingListItem;
    public CheckBox mCheckBox;

    public ShoppingListViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mShoppingListItem = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.shoppingListItem);
        mCheckBox = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.shoppingListCheckBox);
        mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    }

    public void bindShoppingList(Item item){
        mShoppingListItem.setText(item.getItemDescription());
    }


    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        removeAt(getAdapterPosition(),this);
    }
}

public void removeAt(int position,ShoppingListViewHolder viewHolder) {
    mItems.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
}
```

This is my code in MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Toolbar mToolbar;
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private ArrayList<Item> shoppingListItems;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mToolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    shoppingListItems = new ArrayList<>();
    shoppingListItems.add(new Item("Apples"));
    shoppingListItems.add(new Item("Bred"));
    shoppingListItems.add(new Item("Potatoes"));
    shoppingListItems.add(new Item("Muffins"));
    shoppingListItems.add(new Item("Crackers"));
    shoppingListItems.add(new Item("Spaghetti"));
    shoppingListItems.add(new Item("Plastic Bags"));
    shoppingListItems.add(new Item("Deodorant"));
    shoppingListItems.add(new Item("Razors"));
    shoppingListItems.add(new Item("Shampoo"));
    shoppingListItems.add(new Item("Tooth brushes"));
    shoppingListItems.add(new Item("Butter"));
    shoppingListItems.add(new Item("Bagels"));
    shoppingListItems.add(new Item("Coconut water"));
    shoppingListItems.add(new Item("Tomatoes"));

    ShoppingListAdapter adapter = new ShoppingListAdapter(this,shoppingListItems);
    mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new SimpleDividerItemDecoration(getApplicationContext()));
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Notifying that an itemRangeChanged seems redundant to me. I doubt deleting that line would fix your problem but maybe it's worth trying?

Comment: I think the notifyItemRangeChanged is not required since you are already calling notifyItemRemoved

Comment: I removed the method, but the problem is still present :/ It feels like ghost touches :/ Thank you guys!

Comment: If problem still persists, please update your question with the Activity.java file

Comment: it because you don't understand idea of "recycling" in recyclingview ... where are you reseting checkboxes to uncheck state ? ... you should do this on onBindView ... why are you assuming that state of this view is just the same like it was after inflating?

Comment: Hmm, you are right. I don't do that. I am still new to android development. Could you tell me where I should do that? :)

Comment: check the stan answer ... but still ... you really wana delete it on check change? if not, then use my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30759016/recyclerview-viewholder-reusing/30760151#30760151  and treat the `expanded` as `checked`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the "automatically" checked item(s) reuse the view holder of the deleted item (including the checked checkbox). When you [bind](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#onBindViewHolder(VH,%20int)) the ViewHolder try to (re)set the checkbox' state to false:

```
ShoppingListViewHolder {
    public void bindShoppingList(Item item){
        mShoppingListItem.setText(item.getItemDescription());
        mCheckBox.setChecked(false);// <- this
    }
}
```

[`onBindViewHolder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#onBindViewHolder(VH,%20int)) is the place where you set the item's view to match the item's data

Comment: Thank you @stan0 for your reply. That seems to fix this problem with the "ghost touches" but now when I scroll down to the items that are about to be inflated/recycked the app crashes on the line where i am calling: notifyItemRemoved(position);

Comment: "Cannot call this method while RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling"

Comment: the `onCheckedChanged` method is probably called from inside `onBindViewHolder` when you set the checkbox state to "non-checked". Which causes the item to be removed while it's binded to a view holder. I can't find a reference why this is bad/illegal, but it sounds bad to me. I would check the `isChecked` parameter inside `onCheckedChanged` and only call `removeAt` if `isChecked` is true.

Comment: ... or setOnCheckedChangeListener to null before mCheckBox.setChecked and set it back after ...

Comment: Thank you so much, @stan0. That seems to work pretty well. Thank you guys! Much appreciated!